# How to use VMware on multiple displays?

Tags: lubuntu, display, vmware

I am using three displays on my lubuntu 13.04 host machine (GeForce GTX 690).
I need to run many virtual machines and have been using VirtualBox lately. Now I've decided to install VMware. Everything was great: Installed several VMs, set up shared folders and so on.

Everything was great until I tried to drag the window with a VM to another display. It turns out VMware is not displaying guest desktop on secondary displays! When I start machine on a secondary display I can see it downloading and than hanging. When I drag the window to the primary display I see that machine downloaded. Tried both VMWare workstation and Player. All the same.

How do I get this working seamlessly on multiple displays?

Comment: Which software exactly are you using? VMWare Player or VMware workstation? What is the version of lubuntu you are running? Edit your question to reflect the answers to these.

Comment: I'm a little confused. I use VMware Player 6 on Linux and have not hit any issues running multiple players on multiple displays. I may be misunderstanding the problem. I'm on Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit with an nVidia card.

Comment: Some people believe it is a trouble of xinerama, but I can not be sure about that